# How to transfer data from one activity to another using cardviews?

Tags: java, android, cardview

I really want to know how can I transfer data from one activity to another but here is the twist I want it to make a custom *cardview* and store information in it.

Every time someone enters data it makes a *cardview* with their information... Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using static keyword

```
static int a=10;                                                                             
static void display()
{
  System.out.println(a+5);
}
```

You can call static method directly with your activity class.Remember static method can only hold static members.

```
Classname.method();
Classname.variable;
```

Another way to pass data is using Intent & Bundle:-
  Make intent with your destination class and add key with it's value.Put this 
  code in that activity from where you want to send data.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, DestinationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(Key, Value);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now to receive the data

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String str = intent.getStringExtra(Key);
```

To get diff. types of data use getIntExtra(),getFloatExtra(),getStringExtra()

**To access other class variables/methods**                                       Make Object of your activity class and use it with "." seperator in order to use class variables or methods.

```
Classname objname = new Classname();
objname.variable;
objname.method();
```

Ex:-Suppose class name is DemoActivity having variables int a,b and add().

```
DemoActivity objdemo = new DemoActivity();                                      
objdemo.a;                                                                  
objdemo.add();
```

Comment: This is not the correct way to pass data between activity, you have to use the bundle object to pass data between activities

Comment: @Osama.070032 Yes you are right with use of Intent & Bundle you can also pass data between two activities.Thank you for the edit but using the static  and object of class class data can also be accessed/pass.